# Embedding report for power bi user

Tags: powerbi

I have a report in which I want to implement Row-level Security. I have prepared my report, the thing left now is embedding it into a web page.
For that, I have created a blank MVC site.
I have registered my app into an Azure AD and granted all the required permissions. I don't have any master or pro account.
Whenever the user hits the URL, I want to prompt the user for sign-in and after sign-in, I want to pass the role and username to report to implement RLS.

Here is my action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
           try
            {
                AuthenticationContext AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl, false);
                string query = "client_secret="+ClientSecret;
                AuthenticationResult AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientID, new Uri(RedirectUrl), new PlatformParameters(0), UserIdentifier.AnyUser,query);
                if (AuthResult == null)
                {
                    return View(new EmbedConfig()
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed."
                    });
                }
                var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(AuthResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
                using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
                {

                    var reports = client.Reports.GetReports();

                    var report = reports.Value[0];

                    if (report == null)
                    {
                        return View(new EmbedConfig()
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = "Workspace has no reports."
                        });
                    }

                    EffectiveIdentity effectidentity = new EffectiveIdentity(AuthResult.UserInfo.DisplayableId, new List<string>(new string[] { report.DatasetId }), new List<string>(new string[] {"Role1"}));
                    var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest("View", report.DatasetId, false, new List<EffectiveIdentity>(new EffectiveIdentity[] { effectidentity }));

                    var tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateToken(report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

                    if (tokenResponse == null)
                    {
                        return View(new EmbedConfig()
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token."
                        });
                    }

                    var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
                    {
                        Token = tokenResponse.Token,
                        EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
                        Id = report.Id
                    };
                    return View(embedConfig);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return View(new EmbedConfig()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Failed to display report."
                });
            }
        }
```

After this line `AuthenticationResult AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientID, new Uri(RedirectUrl), new PlatformParameters(0));`, it asks for user credentials.

On line `var tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateToken(report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);` it gives an exception saying `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`.

As I don't have any pro user, I am unable to create group id. In that case, I cannot use GenerateTokenInGroup as I don't have any groups.

What to do in this case?

Comment: Without Pro or dedicated capacity, you just can't do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Embedding Power BI artifacts is only available to Premium users of Power BI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium

or via Azure: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-developer-community-october-update/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)